# How to delete something in Tinydb/python in command line python

Tags: python, del, tinydb

Hey i have here my code:

```
elif command == 'del' or command == 'delete':
    Cat_Del = input('Which Category do you wanna delete: ')
    Name_Del = input('Whats the name ')
    Category = Query()
    Name = Query()
    Every_Del = db.search(Category['Category'] == '%s' % Cat_Del
                    and Name['Naam'] == '%s' % Name_Del)

    print(db.all())
```

and here my database:

```
   {"_default": {"1": {"Category": "Fruit", "SubCategory": "zoet", "Naam": 
   "appel", "Cost": "$5"}, "2": {"Category": "Fruit", "SubCategory": "zoet", 
   "Naam": "banaantje", "Cost": "$10"}}}
```

and i wanna know how to delete 'something' from the Delete commando:
elif command == 'del' or command == 'delete'
for example i want to know how to delete only apple out of my database so im gonna run the script and im answering the questions with q1 = Fruit, q2 = appel
but how to delete it then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete record or document from TinyDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022581/how-to-delete-record-or-document-from-tinydb)

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution to the problem but thank you all for viewing this; if you have something better feel free to post it!

db.remove(Category['Category'] == '%s' % Cat_Del
                  and Name['Naam'] == '%s' % Name_Del)